# Change the preferred algorythm from AES to Camellia in an existing PGP key

Tags: aes, gnupg

I already created a PGP key-pair in Thunderbird Enigmail on Ubuntu. Now I would like to change the key, so it uses preferably Camellia-256 for encryption.

How can I change the preferred algorithm from AES 256 to Camellia-256 in my existing key?

UPDATE:
I want to find out how to **add** the information that I prefer CAMELLIA256 to my already **existing PGP key**. I guess this can be done using the commandline somehow like `gpg2 --edit-key ...`
and use `setpref CAMELLIA256` somehow, but I cannot find a good site that explains this syntax

Comment: This is a software-specific configuration question.

Comment: GPG under the hood of anything is very much like GPG under the hood of everything else.  The only thing that changes are the paths and that question even tells you how to get GPG to tell you the path.

Comment: I slightly changed the linked question to make it more general, as the answers indeed are valid for both operating systems.

Comment: The linked answer only shows how to change the behaviour, but here I want to find out how to **add** the information that I prefer CAMELLIA256 to my already **existing PGP key**

Comment: I think, the duplicate link is not correct. The other question is not about the preferred cipher in the keys, but this one is. However, there is also [this question and answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/90598/134095).

Answer (score 0):

You can look up available algorithms by running `gpg --version`, An example output might include:

```
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
```

Start the edit menu using `gpg --edit-key [key-id]` (replacing `[key-id]` with your key id, and you might have to use `gpg.exe` again as described above). Inside, you can use `showpref` to list the currently set up preferences, and `setpref` to change them. The user interface for doing so is *horrible*, and you have to provide a long list of cipher, digest and compression algorithms, while the preferred ones always have to be listed first.

An [article on debian-administration.org](https://debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/48) also describes this procedure, and proposes following preferences, which seem reasonable:

```
setpref CAMELLIA256 SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
```

(There will be a preview of the result, before you really edit the key)

Additionally for future keys, to enforce the use of CAMELLIA256, edit your `gpg.conf` file and add following line:

```
personal-cipher-preferences CAMELLIA256
```